# How to dynamically bind static DependencyProperty defined in a class to a property in another xaml class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a static DependencProperty **IsControlVisibleProperty** in MyControl.xaml.cs.  And its value is changed inside that same class. And I want to listen to this property in another control Visibility property whenever IsControlVisibleProperty value is changed.

**MyControl.xaml.cs :**

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty IsControlVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsControlVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl));
    public bool IsControlVisible
    {
        get{ return (bool)GetValue(IsControlVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsControlVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

    // In a function I am updating the dependency property
    private void UpdateProp(bool isVisible)
    {
        this.SetValue(UserControl1.IsControlVisible, isVisible);
    }
```

Now I want to use IsControlVisibleProperty value in another xaml file
**SampleControl.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converter="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
    Height="300" Width="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:MyControl/>
    <TextBlock Name="ErrorMessage" Text="Failed to run" Visibility="{Binding ElementName="ErrorMessage" , Path=(local:MyControl.IsControlVisible), Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

So my TextBlock (ErrorMessage) is not binding the IsVisibleProperty from MyControl.xaml.cs. I want IsVisibleProperty to be always binded with TextBlock(whereever the property changes it should alse change its visibility ) not just one time on contruction . Unfortunately I am unable to achieve this . Is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: There's really too much here. Your binding can't work, because you are using syntax that _could_ work with a static property, but certainly not an instance property. Even if it did work, you _shouldn't_ be binding one control's property to another. And a visual element like `UserControl` should have _dependency properties_ declared, so that they can be targets of a binding, not just a source. Had you done it that way, then both `MyControl` and `SampleControl` could bind their individual dependency properties (which in the XAML would be bound to the visibility you want) to a view model property

Comment: (And to be clear: when I write "_could_ work", I don't mean that the syntax is actually valid, but rather just that _at best_, it references a static member. In reality, to reference a static member, you need to use the `Source` attribute for the binding, as well as the `{x:Static...}` markup, neither of which are present here.)

Comment: Why do you have `IsControlVisibleProperty ` instead of just using WPF's built-in `Visibility` property?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I cannot use binding as `{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyControls.IsControlVisible}}`. It does not work since DependencyProperty is static but GetValue and SetValue are not.

Comment: _"I cannot use binding as {Binding Source={x:Static local:MyControls.IsControlVisible}}"_ -- I'm not suggesting you do. That would be awful design. I'm just saying that's the closest to the syntax you attempted, to something that could plausibly work.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of a `DependencyProperty` is always static but your `IsControlVisible` property is not static. In fact, you can't declare a `static` dependency property because the `GetValue` and `SetValue` method are not `static`.

What you should is to define an *attached* dependency property in a `static` class:

```
public static class MyProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsControlVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsControlVisible",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyProperties));

    public static void SetIsControlVisible(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsControlVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsControlVisible(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsControlVisibleProperty);
    }
}
```

You can then set this property on any `UIElement` (or whatever the type is in your get and set accessors) using the accessors like this:

```
MyProperties.SetIsControlVisible(this, true); //this = the UserControl
```

You bind to the attached property of the parent `UserControl` like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="ErrorMessage" Text="Failed to run" 
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=(local:MyProperties.IsControlVisible), 
                        Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter},
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: I intend to use this static DependencyProperty for example IsControlVisibleProperty based on its value throughout the application not just for one UIElement. And its value is changed in only one particular class for example in MyControls.xaml.cs. I intend to use the changing value to update a UIElement in another class. Is there any other way to acheive this?

Comment: @Rubina: Again, there is no such thing as a static dependency property. If the property is the same "throughout the application", you should probably consider defining a static CLR property instead of a dependency property.